# Retrieving an object's class name using reflection

Tags: java, class, object, reflection, import

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Member;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class TryReflection {

    public TryReflection() {
        int a = 0;
    }

    public static int getMax() {

        int max = 0;
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TryReflection myObject = new TryReflection();

        int ret = myObject.getMax();
        System.out.printf("max is %d\n", ret);

        Method[] methods = myObject.class.getMethods();
        // for(Method method:methods) {
        // System.out.println("method = " + method.getName());
        // }

    }

}
```

I don't understand why do I get the following error when I compile the above code.

```
TryReflection.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    Method[] methods = myObject.class.getMethods();
                       ^
  symbol:   class myObject
  location: class TryReflection
1 error
```

Comment: You need to use `getClass()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myObject` is an *instance* of a class, so you should use `myObject.getClass()`. Alternatively just call `TryReflection.class`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an instance of your object available, you need to use `myObject.getClass()`

```
TryReflection myObject = new TryReflection();

int ret = myObject.getMax();
System.out.printf("max is %d\n", ret);

Method[] methods = myObject.getClass().getMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    System.out.println("method = " + method.getName());
}
```

Please refer the [**official tutorials**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) for more details.